# RegExp: backreferences inside []

Tags: javascript, regex

```
'"aaa" "bbb"'.match(/("|')[^\1]+\1/g)
// ['"aaa" "bbb"']

'"aaa" "bbb"'.match(/("|')[^"]+\1/g)
// ['"aaa"', '"bbb"']
```

Why does `[^\1]+` instead of `[^"]+` make RegExp greedy?

Comment: JavaScript does not support octal character escapes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does `[^\1]+` instead of `[^"]+` make RegExp greedy?

That isn’t what you think it is doing.

First of all, a `+` is *always* a **maximal match**, the thing you are calling “greedy”. It’s `+?` which is a **minimal match**.

Second and more importantly, back‐referencing doesn’t happen in square‐bracketed character classes.  You have accidentally just asked for any character except for Control‑A.  That’s because backslash followed by digits means that code point in octal notation, as in `\177` for `DELETE` ᴀᴋᴀ `\x7F`, or `\40` for SPACE ᴀᴋᴀ `\x20`, or `\0` for NULL .  So when you wrote `\1`, you have just used U+0001 or `\x01`. Don’t do that. :)

You probably mean to use

```
(["'])(?:(?!\1).)+\1
```

instead.  You’ll need `/s` mode so that dot can match newlines, which I seem to recall Javascript has some screwed‐up–ness with.

---

**EDIT:** According to [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html), clumsy old Javascript has no way to make dot match linebreaks. What rimnods! And of course because Javascript can’t do Unicode regexes, you can’t use the `\p{Any}` required by [UTS#18’s RL1.2](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Categories).

That means you’ll have to use some lame kludge like `[\S\s]` instead if there’s a chance that you might have linebreaks in your quoted strings.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know backreferences isn't allowed in square-bracketed character classes.

Comment: @NV No prob. You aren’t alone — *most* people don’t realize this. And because it can *seem* to work, it often goes unnoticed, further reinforcing the misunderstanding.

Comment: `("|').+?\1` seems to work the same, but looks much simpler. Is it different?

Comment: @NV: Yes, I *think* `(['"]).*?\1` should be fine; it’s what I always use. Just bear in mind it won’t cross linebreaks because you can’t turn off that dot means `[^\n]` in Javascript.  If I can think of a way to do something using maximal matching instead of minimal matching, I usually use it, but lookaheads would slow it down again.

Answer (score 1):

`[^\1]+` doesn't do what you think it does, it matches letters that are not `\` or `1`. These include `"` and `"`'.

A correct alternative, using a negative lookahead:

```
/(["'])(?:(?!\1).)*\1/g
```

or, more simply:

```
/"[^"]*"|'[^']*'/g
```

Comment: Um, no Kobi.  It matches any code point that is not U+0001.  It will certainly match a backslash or a digit one just fine.  Plus I think you have some backslashes or quotes wrong, so maybe the markup is hosing you so you wrote something different form what I’m reading.

Comment: @tchrist. Hmm, you seem to be right about `\1` in a character class. I'm not sure what's the other problem (both patterns seem to work), but I'll it be. Thanks!